# What does gitolite closebranch actually do?

Tags: git, gitolite, atlassian-sourcetree

I was told to use this command line to close out a bug branch in Git, but I really don't like command line and want to use SourceTree GUI. So I'm trying to figure out what this command is actually doing. I suspect it's just tagging the branch and then deleting it. So if you know, please tell me how to do the equivalent of this gitolite closebranch command in SourceTree in Mac OS. Thanks!

```
Usage: <gitolite> closebranch <repository name> <branch name> <reason for closing>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Gitolite user, but a quick search suggests that [this is not a standard command](http://www.justmanpage.com/man/gitolite.1).

Gitolite supports [custom commands](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#ncintro). Perhaps your administrator has created a custom command called `closebranch`? You could try `gitolite closebranch -h` to see if there are standard help docs provided.

If this doesn't help (and even if it does), it might be a good idea to ask the server administrator what the command is meant to do.

Comment: It turns out you're correct. My admin made it so that normal delete branch is not permitted unless I use this command which tags and delete. Thanks for the answer, I was getting no where searching on google.